# Error while uploading file","error":["local variable 'upload_file_path' referenced before assignment" - in Karate for post method with ".yaml" file

Tags: karate

A simple test to post '.yaml' on service, hosted on my local machine.

Feature: Test

```
Background:
 * url 'http://localhost:0000/upload' ..........(anonymized)

Scenario: Test
  Given path 'contract'
  And multipart entity read('test.yaml')        ..........(anonymized)
  And multipart field digest = '123123dedwd2rd2d23e2d23e2d3'      .........(anonymized)
  And header Content-Type = 'multipart/related'
  When method post
  Then status 200
```

Response is `{"message":"Error while uploading file","error":["local variable 'upload_file_path' referenced before assignment"],"success":false}`

Need help to understand, what local variable `upload_file_path` is referenced here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate auto-converts `*.yaml` files as JSON by default because that is the most common use case, but you are trying to do a file-upload. You have 2 options.

a) Rename the file to something else, e.g. `*.txt`

b) use the [`karate.readAsString()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#csv-files) API

```
And multipart entity karate.readAsString('test.yaml')
```

EDIT: as per comment

To pass a custom `Content-Type` you can do 2 steps:

```
* def temp = karate.readAsString('test.yaml')
* multipart file file = { value : '#(temp)', filename: 'myname.yml', contentType: 'application/yaml' }
```

Comment: Solution only accepts input in `*.yaml` (it content schema of data load)

`And multipart entity karate.readAsString('test.yaml’)` (upload file in feature root folder)
`And multipart entity karate.readAsString('classpath:test.yaml’)` (upload file in Java root folder)

results in same error message …

Comment: @JayeshS no idea what you are saying follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: The API is suppose to ingest only ".yaml" file & its schema of data load to happen in future, hence cant change file to *.txt.

I was able to solve issue, by implementing 
 - “karate.readAsString” &
 - “multipart file” file = { value : '#(temp)', filename: "<fileUpload>", contentType: 'application/yaml'}